# How does one interpret an element of k[V]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

If $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $V$ is an affine variety, what does it mean for some $f$ to lie in $k[V]$? Can someone give an example of such an $f$?

Thanks,
Kartik

Comment: Do you know the definition of $k[V]$?

Comment: I just have a definition from my class notebook,
$k[V] = \{f:V\to k| f \quad\text{is the restriction of a polynomial}\}$ = $k[x_1,...,x_n]/\mathbb{I}(V)$. Can you explain $k[V]$ through an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $k[V]$ is called the *coordinate ring* of the affine variety $V\subset k^n$.

Let me start out by explaining in words what an element of $k[V]$ is like: The basic object that $k[V]$ comes from is the ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and to obtain some element $\bar{f}\in k[V]$, you lump together some of the polynomials of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ in a certain way. This means that the element $\bar{f}\in k[V]$ is really a class of polynomials that all have something in common - some trait with respect to the affine variety $V$ that leads us to not wanting to distinguish between the different polynomials in the class $\bar{f}$, and hence we end up grouping them together.

Specifically, we lump together polynomials of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ that represent the same function on $V$. That two polynomials $f$ and $g$ represent the same function on $V$ means that their difference is $0$ on $V$. In other words, you cannot tell $f$ and $g$ apart, when you consider their values only on the set $V$.

Now, how does the mathematics work out?

If you define the coordinate ring as

$$k[V] := k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathbb{I}(V),$$

recall that $\mathbb{I}(V)$ is the set of polynomials that are $0$ on all of $V$. This means that an element $\bar{f}:=[f]\in k[V]$ is the equivalence class represented by the polynomial $f$, and that all other elements $g\in [f]$ in this class have the property that $f-g$ is $0$ on $V$. This is exactly what I explained in words above.

This is also the reason why you write $k[V] = \{f:V\to k| f\ \text{is the restriction of a polynomial}\}$, because if two different polynomials $g,h\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ become the same polynomial function $f$ when restricted to $V$, then they belong to the same class in $k[V]$: They are indistinguishable on $V$, as they attain precisely the same values on $V$.

As an example, consider the affine variety $V=V(y-x^2)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. The ideal $\mathbb{I}(V)$ is the set of polynomials that are $0$ on $V$. For instance, all of $y-x^2,\ x(y-x^2),\ \text{and }y^2x(y-x^2)$ are elements of $\mathbb{I}(V)$. Consider also the polynomial $f=x^5+y^2x$ on $V$. Then the element $\bar{f}\in k[V]$ is a class of polynomials, and examples of elements in this class are $f,\ f+y-x^2,\ f+x(y-x^2),\ f+y^2x(y-x^2)$, or more generally, an element of the form $f+P(x,y)(y-x^2)$ for some polynomial $P(x,y)\in k[x,y]$. You see that all the polynomials in the class $\bar{f}$ attain the same values on all of $V$.